# Is is possible to use an old, custom database of users, with IdentityServer4

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

I have an old .net based system with its own, custom, database of users.

Can I implement IdentityServer4, such that all login and related requests are delegated to my legacy application, either via API of that application, or directly accessing the legacy DB?

If so, are there any examples or how-tos for this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its trivial to integrate existing users with IdentityServer. The really nice thing is that all you need to is to implement the [IProfileService](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html?highlight=IProfileService#iprofileservice-apis) interface.

IdentityServer never writes to the user database, its read-only. So its just a simple load operation that you need to implement to get it to work.

Also see this [link](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/18897890ce2cb020a71b836db030f3ed1ae57882/src/IdentityServer4/src/Test/TestUserProfileService.cs) and this [link](https://github.com/dgmteam/wiki/blob/a98e6001def0617fae9bede8827064d3e3cb802f/_aspnet_core/itentity_server_4/recipe-itentity-server-4-custom-profile.md)